# ANDROID: get current GPS location never call "onLocationChanged"

Tags: android, gps

trying to get current Longitude and Latitude.

CODE:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locationListener = new myLocationListener();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 1, locationListener);
    }

    class myLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            tvLang.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location changed: Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + " Lng: " + loc.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

but when I run it on my LG G2 - it never get into the "onLocationChanged" function.
the GPS is On, i can find myself in Google Maps.
tried to restart the phone few times.

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: may be the GPS was never able to give you a location. Instead of using GPS_PROVIDER, could you try Network_PROVIDER?

Comment: Yes, with NETWORK_PROVIDER its working, does it means that I have problem with my GPS? Google maps working great..

Comment: Google map uses all kinds of provider, you might want to step outside where a GPS signal can be locked

Comment: the thing is - It's very important that it will work inside of a house . how can I fix it to work inside?

Comment: I don't think you can physically get a GPS signal indoor. What you could do is to use a combination of NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER together.